# Why my perf_event_open() can be used for only 509 times?

Tags: caching, perf

I use perf_event_open() to measure the cache miss rate.
I do this by:

```
double cachemiss(int PID_NUM){
    int i;double rate;
    struct perf_event_attr pe;
    int fd1,fd2;
    uint64_t miss,reference;
    uint64_t id1, id2;
    struct read_format buf;
    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
    pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
    pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MISSES;
    pe.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;
    fd1 = perf_event_open(&pe, PID_NUM, -1, -1, 0);
    ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &id1);
    if (fd1 == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pe.config);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
    pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
    pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_REFERENCES;
    pe.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;
    fd2 = perf_event_open(&pe, PID_NUM, -1, fd1, 0);
    ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &id2);
    if (fd2 == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pe.config);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);
    ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);
    usleep(10000);
    ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);
    read(fd1, &buf, sizeof(buf));
    for (i = 0; i < buf.nr; i++) {
        if (buf.values[i].id == id1) miss = buf.values[i].value;
        else if (buf.values[i].id == id2) reference =buf.values[i].value;
    }
    rate=(double)miss/((((double)reference+(double)miss))+1);
    return rate;
}
int main()
{
    for(int i=0;1;i++) cout<<i<<"\t"<<cachemiss(11);
}
```

Then, the beginning 509 times have nothing wrong.
But when it comes to the 510th time, fd2=-1.
I try it again and again, but the problem is always same: the 510 times doesn't work.

Comment: When syscall returns -1 you should check `errno` value and decode it with man page. perf_event_open lists some codes http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html#ERRORS and "*-1 if an error occurred (in which case, errno is set appropriately).*". You may have some resource leak or limit (fd returned by syscall should be closed like `close(fd);` in the [man page usage example](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html#EXAMPLE)). Please update the question with errno value and check `ulimit -a`.

Answer (score 2):

You have resource leak in every iteration and some limit activated. There can be hint about resource in the value of `errno` special variable when fd is -1, check man page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html#ERRORS

> RETURN VALUE ... -1 if an error occurred (in which case, errno is set appropriately)

Resource limits ca be checked with `ulimit -a` command in shell (bash).

[Example of perf_event_open() usage in man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html#EXAMPLE) has close syscall on the fd returned by syscall:

> ```
>    fd = perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0);
>    if (fd == -1) {
>       fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pe.config);
>       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
>    }
>    ....
>    read(fd, &count, sizeof(long long));
>
>    close(fd);
> ```

And your `cachemiss()` has no close syscall for fd1 and fd2, so file descriptors are leaking at speed of two per iteration.